# Changing html in a function

Tags: php, html, function

I'm moving some of my html into my functions.php file and changing these html into a function which I then can call back into my template files where needed.

This is just one part of my html that display a twitter and facebook button in an author box with URL's that will connect to the authors facebook and twitter pages

```
<div class="profile-links">

                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'facebook' ) != '' ) ?>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/<?php echo wp_kses( get_the_author_meta( 'facebook' ), null ); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Follow %s on Facebook', 'pietergoosen'), get_the_author() ); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/facebook.png" height="32px" width="32px" alt="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Follow %s on Facebook', 'pietergoosen'), get_the_author() ); ?>" /></a>


                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter' ) != '' )  ?>
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/<?php echo wp_kses( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter' ), null ); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Follow %s on Twitter', 'pietergoosen'), get_the_author() ); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/twitter.png" height="32px" width="32px" alt="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Follow %s on twitter', 'pietergoosen'), get_the_author() ); ?>" /></a>


        </div>
```

This is the code so far for this particular section that I put into function

```
 foreach ( $services as $name  => $service ){

$authorDetails = get_the_author();
$AuthorMeta = get_the_author_meta( $service['name'] );

 $services = array (
        'facebook' => array (
            'url'  => "http://www.facebook.com/' . echo . 'wp_kses( $AuthorMeta, null )'",
            'text' => 'Follow %s on Facebook'
        ),
 'twitter' => array (
            'url'  => "http://www.twitter.com/' . echo . 'wp_kses( $AuthorMeta, null )'",
            'text' => 'Follow %s on Twitter'
        )
    );
}

    $img_base = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/%s.png';

    foreach ( $services as $name  => $service ){
    if ( $AuthorMeta  != '' )  { 
        $href = sprintf( $service['url'] );
        $src  = sprintf( $img_base, $name );
        $size = '32';

    echo '<div class="profile-links">';

          printf(
              '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s"><img src="%3$s" alt="%2$s" height="%4$d" width="%4$d"/></a>',
              $href,
              esc_attr( __( $service['text'], 'pietergoosen' ), $authorDetails ),
              $src,
            $size
        );

    echo '</div>';

    }
}
```

My problem is that I'm not getting the URL's correctly. How do I convert the URL in the html to the one that I must use in the 'url' field in my function. I hope all the code I supplied make sense

Comment: you should tag this for wordpress too

Comment: Is this a wordpress question?

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write `echo` when concatenating values. And calls to functions should not be inside quotes. So it should be:

```
$services = array (
    'facebook' => array (
        'url'  => "http://www.facebook.com/" . wp_kses( $AuthorMeta, null ),
        'text' => 'Follow %s on Facebook'
    ),
     'twitter' => array (
        'url'  => "http://www.twitter.com/" . wp_kses( $AuthorMeta, null ),
        'text' => 'Follow %s on Twitter'
    )
);
```